# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html

Tags: python, flask

I looked at this question and found that everyone as a similar problem then the other:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/")
@app.route('/home')
def home():
   return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Error** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\__pycache__\flaskblog.py", line 10, in home
    return render_template('home.html')
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 58, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "C:\Users\LEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 86, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html
```

Comment: Your question needs massive editing. Please add more details about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The function `render_template()` looks for html templates in a folder called `templates`. Make sure your project has this folder and all html files are placed inside it. More details about a typical Flask project structure can be found [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/layout/#project-layout).

Comment: yes my html files, are in the only file that is not in is my flask file.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your comment. Do you have a folder called `templates` in your project and does it have the html files inside it? The flask file should be outside this folder.

Comment: Great! You may upvote or accept as answer if this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of the directory name. It should be "templates" and not "template". I was doing same mistake and it got resolved now